# time delay on focus action

Tags: ios, swift, focus

I've got a Collection View and have arranged it in such a way that there is a single column on one side of the screen and content that is replaced based on what collection item is in focus.

I'd like to be able to on swap the content out if focus on an item has been held for more then .5 seconds.

Here is what I currently have, and it swaps the data out instantly.

```
if self.focused {
   self.label.alpha = 1
   self.priceLabel.alpha = 1
   if self.representedDataItem?.imageUrl! == "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/random/image.png" ||
      self.representedDataItem?.imageUrl! == "" {
           self.backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "titleImage")
   }
   else {
      ImageCache.sharedLoader.imageForUrl((self.representedDataItem?.imageUrl!)!, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
           self.backgroundImage.image = image!
      })
   }
}
else {
   self.label.alpha = 0.2
   self.priceLabel.alpha = 0.2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the `self.focused` how to determine, assume you already took care of it. Therefore, you could use `GCD` to delay the execution while focused.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,  Int64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // code to be executed after 0.5 sec
}
```

Comment: By Wrapping this around the "if self.representedDataItem?.imageUrl!" statement all this did was simply delay the roll through that was happening instantly. Being that I only wanted to restrict the image swap out, but not the alpha changes, I pulled the image code out of the original "if self.focused" and placed it inside your code, with a new "if self.focused" wrapping it. I'll post my final code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
if self.focused {
   self.label.alpha = 1
   self.priceLabel.alpha = 1
}
else {
   self.label.alpha = 0.2
   self.priceLabel.alpha = 0.2
}
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,  Int64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // code to be executed after 0.5 sec
    if self.focused {
        if self.representedDataItem?.imageUrl! == "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/random/image.png" ||
           self.representedDataItem?.imageUrl! == "" {
               self.backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "titleImage")
        }
        else {
            ImageCache.sharedLoader.imageForUrl((self.representedDataItem?.imageUrl!)!, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
                self.backgroundImage.image = image!
            })
        }
    }
}
```